# CppUTest example doesn't work

Tags: macos, cpputest

I just installed CppUTest on my MAC using brew as indicated by the guide.
It failed when I tried to build the example cpp.

```
TEST_GROUP(FirstTestGroup)
{
};

TEST(FirstTestGroup, FirstTest)
{
   FAIL("Fail me!");
}
```

I guess it is because the header file which define those macros are not  included. So I add include as below:

```
#include "CppUTest/TestHarness.h"
#include "CppUTest/TestOutput.h"
TEST_GROUP(FirstTestGroup)
{
};

TEST(FirstTestGroup, FirstTest)
{
   FAIL("Fail me!");
}
```

Now I get bunch of errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "UtestShell::assertTrue(bool, char const*, char const*, char const*, int)", referenced from: vtable for TEST_FirstTestGroup_FirstTest_TestShellin ccNDwnbv.o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is a linker error and it suggests that you are not linking the CppUTest library. It is hard to actually say what is wrong because your question is missing the Makefiles. Could you explain how you have compiled the example?

Comment: Hello, Bas. I write a simple makefile like this:
    CC=gcc
    CXX=g++

    CPPUTEST_HOME=/root/usr/cpputest-3.4

    FLAGS= -c

    CPPFLAGS += -I$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/include
    LD_LIBRARIES = -L$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/lib -lCppUTest -lCppUTestExt


   TARGET=TryTest

    OBJECTS=TryTest.o
    SOURCES=TryTest.cpp
 
    $(TARGET):$(OBJECTS)

Then use make to build the target.

Comment: Try to use LDFLAGS instead of LD_LIBRARIES and you will also need to add -lstdc++ to it.